# Typescript: Mapped types with Interface

Tags: typescript, types, interface, mapped-types

When trying to use mapped types with interface, i get a weird error - which makes me think its not possible to use them together at all..

See identical type and interface declarations:

```
type AllWorks<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K];
}

interface DoesNotWork<T> {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K];
}
```

While first one works as  expected, second one gives the TS error:

```
[ts] A computed property name must be of type 'string', 'number', 'symbol', or 'any'.
[ts] Member '[K in keyof' implicitly has an 'any' type.
[ts] Cannot find name 'keyof'.
```

So my question is - **is it even possible to map over interfaces ? if yes - then how ?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So far in TypeScript (as of version 2.7.2), union type signatures in interfaces are not allowed and instead mapped types should be used (as you correctly have).

[Docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html).

Answer (score -1):

Interfaces are not built with such a purpose. You should use `Type` there instead.

The Typescript compiler is telling you that you are using the wrong tool for the job :)

The most complex thing an interface can do is `extend` otherwise use mapped types as a general rule.

I've built an article [here](https://medium.com/better-programming/mastering-typescripts-mapped-types-5fa5700385eb) about mapped types if you want to dig deeper.