# Template literal containing keyof used as an interface key

Tags: typescript, template-literals

Given a simple interface:

```js
interface Schedule {
  interval: "month" | "day";
  price: number;
}
```

I can construct a template-literal type (using `ts4.4`):

```js
type PrefixedScheduleKey = `schedule__${keyof Schedule}`; // "schedule__interval" | "schedule__price"
```

Let's say there are a few of such interfaces and I'd like to merge (essentially flatten) their prefixed, template-literal keys to end up with:

```js
interface Metadata {
  foo: string;
  bar: string;
  // computed 
  schedule__interval: "month" | "day";
  schedule__price: number;
  ...
}
```

How should I declare such interface keys?

```js
interface Metadata {
  [key: PrefixedScheduleKey]: any
}

// throws 
// An index signature parameter type cannot be a literal type or generic type. Consider using a mapped object type instead.(1337)
```

And

```js
interface Metadata {
  [key in `schedule__${keyof Schedule}`]: any 
}

// leads to
// A computed property name must be of type 'string', 'number', 'symbol', or 'any'.(2464)
// Member '[key in `schedule__${keyof' implicitly has an 'any' type.(7008)
```

Here's the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoIBYQCYFcA2KA3gFDLKiRQBuc+AXMgEQC2A9uBk8gD7MCeEOFCYBuMsgAOUYEkYhcLAEbRxAXxIkw-SSgAKUCDGAAPHOix5CAaQj9kAXmQADAM6YcBCAH1vAEiIAazs2GDQPKwg1Z3ESSmh4JGQAWWgAcxxUsDhsOGyARmRSchg2NkZXMBkQNPFyJWEKqtBazXIAbWD+RgMjU3MIr1t+AF1GOBB+dU0AegAqOPAExBRUqAzsLJy8uAAmIolS8uRK6tb6xpPmmtiOrooQF3dLL18ArtDwl8JoseQJ+wkDRzGZAA).

BTW, it was [suggested on github](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24220#issuecomment-390063153) to use `type` instead of `interface` but that won't work because my `Metadata` interface already extends another interface but I tried to keep the example simple.

Comment: How about `interface Metadata extends AnotherInterface, Record<PrefixedScheduleKey, any> {}` ?

Comment: That works, thanks @Jean-Alphonse! Feel free to convert it to an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't possible to do directly on an interface, as documented here: [Typescript: Mapped types with Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49284689/1426891)

> So far in TypeScript (as of version 2.7.2), union type signatures in
> interfaces are not allowed and instead mapped types should be used (as
> you correctly have).
>
> [Docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html).

However, you can implement this with an intersection type between an arbitrary interface and a mapped type, [as in the original GitHub issue you mentioned](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/24220#issue-324164218) ("Moves other members to a separate object type that gets combined with an intersection type"). You can also use the [`as` keyword](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) to effectively inline your `PrefixedScheduleKey` template-literal type while retaining your `Key` long enough to refer to `Schedule[Key]`. There's no reason you couldn't do the same with other prefixed types, either in the same mapped metadata type or in adjacent ones that you intersect with later.

For reference, `key` is capitalized to `Key` when used as a type variable in mapped types, as on the [mapped types handbook page](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html).

```
interface BareMetadata /* extends ArbitraryType */ {
  foo: string;
  bar: string;
}

type ScheduleMetadata = {
  [Key in keyof Schedule as `schedule__${Key}`]: Schedule[Key];
}

type MergedMetadata = BareMetadata & ScheduleMetadata;

const example: MergedMetadata = {
  foo: "one",
  bar: "two",
  schedule__interval: "month",
  schedule__price: 9.99
};
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoIBYQCYFcA2KA3gFDLKiRQBuc+AXMgEQC2A9uBk8gD7MCeEOFCYBuMsgAOUYEkYhcLAEbRxAXxIlK0eEmQAhYRACyEMHGxxzyAPQAqZBAAekENgDOyAIJQlwMFDC-AAq-JIodjbIpOQwbGyM7gGgAObi5ErCickgaSQaJGBhKOhYeISm5pbWALzREgDaANIQ-BQgyADWrWwwaJg4BChwngAG7gPlEAD60wAkRC38aqMAuoylg4TNravqmkXhyKZQKTiVFlZwyHWGUCZml9YAZP1lQxfVcOIkCBxJjiccBYkkIjBOZ2wnyuN3qsXijCYHAgTAANBJMlBEWAAO5sNESCbvQizbQ0OiI9icAnkIlbGbTaSyCCMACcADpWaz8uIgA)

You can even [have the `interface` extend an object-like `type`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/13604), which might help you avoid the explicit intersection:

```
interface MergedMetadata extends BareMetadata, ScheduleMetadata {}
// or
interface Metadata extends ScheduleMetadata {
  foo: string;
  bar: string;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoIBYQCYFcA2KA3gFDLKiRQBuc+AXMgEQC2A9uBk8gD7MCeEOFCYBuMsgAOUYEkYhcLAEbRxAXxIlK0eEmQAhYRACyEMHGxxzyAPQAqZBAAekENgDOyAIJQlwMFDC-AAq-JIodjbIpOQwbGyM7gGgAObi5ErCickgaSQaJGBhKOhYeISm5pbWALzREgDaANIQ-BQgyADWrWwwaJg4BChwngAG7gPlEAD60wAkRC38aqMAuoylg4TNravqmtqwiCimUCk4lRZWcI4uEG6ehlAmZlfmADT9ZUOX1TdEBUOuhOrz+t1cHi+WxeVWu9Vi8WyMly6WQmSgSNS+xICA4SVucBYkkIAEZGKdzthfnC6jFkHEEswOBAmO8JOjGEwwAB3NisiQTb6EWaHWgMZjsTj88iC6GzaSyCCMACcADplcr8uIcXiwASiYQAEzk0E0+H0xFMkAstkZLLMHl823IWVTEXgaBizmSsBcZ2uobymRyZBqjVakhAA)

Comment: Thanks -- works great!

Comment: @Joe You're welcome. See update: While researching this, I learned something new too. :)

Comment: Thanks -- I learned something new too. I find it somewhat confusing that they call it an "intersection" when I think of it as a "union". I'd expect a "strict intersection" of multiple distinct interfaces to be `never` 

Comment: @Joe-ElasticsearchHandbook That mental model took me a while too. It helped me to think of it like this: A union means "this value could be any of these interfaces, so your interactions must be with only the properties they all have in common". An intersection is "this value must match all of these interfaces, so you can interact with properties specified on any contributing interface without checking".

Comment: Great analogy @Jeff.

Comment: Please consider renaming the `key` type parameter in your mapped type to `Key` or `K`.  Type parameters are conventionally written in uppercase (and usually with a single character); they are not key names.  This contrasts with index signatures like `{[k: string]: XXX}`, where the `k` is a dummy key name.

Comment: @jcalz Done in blurb and code signature, with some body text + citation added. I had hoped to keep consistency with the question, but the etiquette in changing the question there might be a little different compared to an answer. For my part, in the future I wouldn't mind if you just made the change as an edit.