# Template literal from keyof in class

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to combine a bunch of TypeScript features at once.

I created a class which is initialized with an object, and has a bunch of functions which should only be able to take as arguments keys of that object. So far so good. [Got some help with that yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72252087/only-accept-keys-of-a-given-object/72252155#72252155), and my basic setup looks like this:

```
class MyClass<Type> {
  properties: Partial<Type> = {};

  constructor(properties: Type) {
    this.properties = properties;
  }
  
  pick(...propNames: Array<keyof Type>) {
    return propNames.reduce((obj, name) => ({ 
      ...obj, 
      [name]: this.properties[name]
    }), {} as Partial<Type>);
  }
}
```

But I actually want ***both*** the keys themselves, and slightly modified versions of those keys to be accepted -- specifically, both `"key"` and `"key!"`. In my case, if you append an exclamation to the key, that (acceptable) input is used to indicate that the key is required.

I found [template literals](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html) in the handbook, and saw that I could do something like this:

```
type Name = 'John';
type BangName = `${Name}!`;
```

Perfect! However, I have no idea how to integrate this into my use case, in which the first type is generated from `keyof`, and this integration is occurring inside a JS class.

I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69226695/template-literal-containing-keyof-used-as-an-interface-key), which gets close. It suggests that I could do something like the below, which generates a combined interface, from which I can derive acceptable keys using `keyof`:

```
type BangType = {
  [Key in keyof Type as `${Key}!`]: Type[Key];
}

type CombinedType = Type & BangType;
```

and then:

```
pick(...propNames: Array<keyof CombinedType>) {
```

But I don't know ***where*** I can generate this `CombinedType`, since the generic `Type` is defined in the class signature. Is this possible?

The below doesn't seem to work:

```
pick(...propNames: Array<keyof PropType> | Array<Key in keyof PropType as `${Key}!`>)
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w1yVAw) meet your needs?  I don't really quite get how your implementation is going to deal with `"!"` so I threw something together; if that's not relevant then maybe remove the implementation from your example code?  Anyway if it works for you I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: It rarely has an effect when I say this, but [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) iterate over *keylike type parameters* and not *key names*, so they conventionally start with a capital letter like any other type parameter; so `{[k in XXX]: YYY}` is unconventional, while `{[K in XXX]: YYY}` is conventional.  Please consider changing `key in keyof ...` to `Key in keyof ...` or `K in keyof ...`.
}

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm, and I will follow the convention. If you want to make that an official answer for points, I'd love to accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can indeed use [template literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#template-literal-types) here.  If you want `propNames` to be an array of either `keyof T` or "the strings you get if you append `"!"` to the end of the strings in `keyof T`", then the type you're looking for is

```
Array<keyof T | `${Extract<keyof T, string>}!`>
```

Note that since `T` is some [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type you don't control, it's possible for it to have some `symbol`-valued keys.  And since [`keyof T` may have `symbol`s in it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html#support-number-and-symbol-named-properties-with-keyof-and-mapped-types), the compiler will be unhappy if you try to just write the template literal type `` `${keyof T}!` `` directly, because template literal types can only serialize `string`s and `number`s (uh, and `bigint`s, and `boolean`s, and `null` and `undefined`.  But that's it):

```
oops(...propNames: Array<keyof T | `${keyof T}!`>) { } // error!
// ---------------------------------> ~~~~~~~
// 'symbol' is not assignable to 'string | number | bigint | boolean | null | undefined'.
```

Since we're just interested in the `string`-valued keys of `T`, we use [the `Extract<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#extracttype-union) to grab just those.  And then the compiler does not complain:

```
pick(...propNames: Array<keyof T | `${Extract<keyof T, string>}!`>) {
  return propNames.map(k =>
    typeof k === "string" ? k.replace(/!$/, "") as keyof T : k
  ).reduce((obj, name) => ({
    ...obj,
    [name]: this.properties[name]
  }), {} as Partial<T>);
}
```

And let's make sure it works:

```
const n = new MyClass({ a: 1, b: "two", c: true });    
const x = n.pick("b!");
console.log(x) // {b: "two"}
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcUA8AVAfNA3gKGmgAcAnAeyIFMSAXAS0ogC5oAFMWusEDbAXlwBfANx4C0YGQB2EGiQCuwGmRIAKUhWr1GLdAEpc4wjQAWdCADoNVTo2gDrWhhFGFBYwmQoRVFv9YA5MABbHWgAQRISMHhUAGtKeDIAM2h0aAAfaAADABIcBKTU9EEAQmzMAxxoQWgAejroanISUvEG6ABabp7evv6BvuwAP1Gx4fbG9HgqaAByCHhggCMyEDnoc2gpMhpoSAg6AHMpMGWQSmhlK5nLhbk6KSPM7fkV6hfl48e9rNW1yhgKQvKTyEAgF7yKQAE0oyUelGhcwsHmIdGAcV8-nIRCCoWYESiMXiiRSaReeRwAFEAB5yMBKElFNIAGmgshIjyOmDKFSqRmgJEoNHkJGBgRCjAswTARFUcXsmAFxluZIVfA10AARByuVroAB+aBxCxCojgYCUVR1Uq5OpsrVagyQY2k4rQFhxAV6U2IxRW1RkZYAKzZp1CBj42FU+EIcegfgsQdDyugAG1w5QALosUzmKw4pyMDOSrMCwR6Nk4Wou9icbi8PSuGp4dx4SQyPbAgRSSgAdzgSBQPmqYBYAEY2csWFqaH2yFq2cBcwpLhXRO3pLJoDT7NsrOjMVrlqUnaIOxAARYQGQjqoaQYOjhp9q5wvBEA)