# Template literal from string in class if string matches certain characteristics

Tags: typescript

I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72264448/template-literal-from-keyof-in-class?noredirect=1#comment127671748_72264448) a bit back, trying to create a class where both a set of keys could be used as args or that set of keys modified with an additional "!".

I landed, consequently, with a class that looks something like this:

```
export class Schema<PropType extends Record<string, any>> {
  properties: Partial<PropType> = {};

  constructor(properties: PropType) {
    this.properties = properties;
  }

  /**
   * Select specific fields *among those already selected*.
   */
  pick = <K extends keyof PropType | `${Extract<keyof PropType, string>}!`>(
    ...fields: Array<K>
  ) => {
    const newProperties = {} as Record<keyof PropType, unknown>;
    fields.forEach((field) => {
      const { name, required } = this._parse(field);
      newProperties[name] = {
        ...(this.properties[name]),
        required,
      };
    });

    return new Schema<Record<K, unknown>>(
      newProperties
    );
  };

    /**
   * Parse a field string, returning the base field "name", and
   * whether the field is required (if it ends in a !).
   */
  _parse = (field: keyof PropType | `${Extract<keyof PropType, string>}!`) => {
    return {
      name: (field as string).replace("!", "") as keyof PropType,
      required: (field as string).split("").reverse()[0] === "!",
    };
  };
}
```

The `pick` function is where the magic happens. It lets me pick both 'keyName' and 'keyName!' if 'keyName' is one of the keys of PropType. In my case, the '!' means that the key is required.

```
const Person = new Schema({ firstName: 'Fyodor', middleName: 'Mikhailovich', lastName: 'Dostoevsky' });

const SubPerson = Person.pick('firstName', 'lastName!');
```

The trouble is, if I "layer" `pick` calls, it adds on exclamation points:

```
SubPerson.pick(
  'firstName', 
  'lastName!', 
  'lastName!!' // Uh-oh! This shouldn't be acceptable
)
```

[See the playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBAYwDYEMDOa4GUEAtgC2KAPAApQRgAqAnmMHKDMAHYAmmASsAtG8WhhQAliwDmAGjgoWNAHxy4AbwBQcOGAr1Yw4GgBccUih0okZLbXqKAvMoC%20AbhVq4AegBUH13G-rfcAACYCYoBHAsYQwAclFwEABmcDD4cGh4hChwABTAYnAA8lBiMsIAXigwwhAsUqTAUGg1UsAwCACUPh5BIVBhGloNVXpwAIIs8QBGAFY88FDAmnqsVeLJqWit8UkF9CyjpACSALS8BGBIwjLwmpRDupgJ0OvCmOn4RF1urrwsglAAVwQMGg2Vu2mGBiMljowHayh8LzQADpwfcRnY0To9M51PYXOpPH51N0sMAkHM0vQEMIEsIEHA6eSOL4wjV8ikIJtpEgFig2DQ0uS5sA2B5kV9XGB6QBrOB2YgAaUYIGY7EwMuANES0MoVgYAB84AADAAkSgAoqq%20sDiJrtUlyHrYVJ-qIxHJ7ABCY1ybKI5GBplIDiGUZQPo0JVyVzwmyKVT%20RA1QQRYAAdydEIe8oc0i4PD4dq1Oqz%20qkAJYMpYEHTLDkuP8wY4yKeUAtKDw2WyzbjCcR6l%20qaUESiUgWAEcAcIFmw4PZcylXsiAPq9TY93Qh9qNpMsDNZ9FoADakQIwAAurnE0n-IHkdklyisZDT1EL%200JAP-JPp7Ov7e867vOO4Ej%20rQAlAEz7um2AZEQxDcLwUD8IqFZVjWdYKP6gEwYe2JoIioF4s4iJEl0RgmNyWTNmkQjuuOEFQe66wMJM6AMLRABEZ7AFxUgyGwFHpvgKQNKxjJbnOrxwL%20M6ijktJwMI8CsCyojSHAXrtBK-geN86hrlRDB2JuzKGPapYwvQcBGmalrWp2MDFg6urUC6dEiOIno%20n2CJJgsMCQRMN57lEhhmSG%20aee6OkLBcnbANkXFevxcBcVx8LoHAlmOtZwAAbecmzhFtHZW64g6WgFwqclmXIgsABuDQbu0x4AAxXjY3XpalhUka4TgqPiKhDvA9SNDUuYwXBHwoNkI50o0MCxOehgAOQAGLamw0DrVIBDCGwbAUqtwAbQAssIMq4CgwhIBAjX0rg%201wKgghnRtAAiXIgsAjVoDKNDrSBpFjdgAKTBNTQTHY0M1KisrZOtS0fVEr3re9K1RF662gVgkPwywiMIDKOFwCjM5o%20er2uJj6DY%20euNSHTWNnV6uPuG4cAAKq4McEC4F6cBULgMloLgEAAiGLDrfAkwMJ2CCLDAKCTBSKjtEAA). Is there a way to allow `${Extract<keyof PropType, string>}!` **IFF** `keyof PropType` doesn't already have a "!"?

Comment: Like [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NDyP4m)?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: Really what you want is [this](https://tsplay.dev/m04oqm) though; you don't want to allow `K` to have an extra `"!"` at the end, just `field`.  Would that work for you instead?

Comment: Man, you are a TypeScript wizard. Every time I think something's impossible, you know exactly how to do it.

Comment: All right I'll add it to my backlog of answers I need to write (hopefully soon)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to detect string [literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) that end in `"!"`, you can use a "pattern literal type" as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#40598](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/40598):

```
type EndsWithExclamation = `${string}!`
let v: EndsWithExclamation;
v = "okay!" // okay
v = "problem?" // error
```

So you *could* just use [the `Exclude<T, U>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion) to filter any strings ending in `"!"` out of `keyof T`:

```
type QuietKeys<T extends object> = Exclude<keyof T, `${string}!`>;
type X = QuietKeys<{ firstName: unknown, lastName: unknown, "lastName!": unknown }>;
// type X = "firstName" | "lastName"
```

Like this:

```
pick = <K extends keyof T | `${Extract<Exclude<keyof T, `${string}!`>, string>}!`>(
  ...fields: Array<K>
) => {
```

*But*, you probably don't really want to do that.  The return type of `pick()` is `Schema<Record<K, unknown>>`.  So if you pass in a field like `"firstName!"`, then the output type will be `Schema<{"firstName!": unknown}>`.  But if the actual field name was `firstName`, then you'd want to see `Schema<{firstName: unknown}>` instead.  You don't want to *output* the exclamation point.

---

The way I'd do this is to key `K extends keyof T` only, so that you know that `K` will definitely be keys from the original object type and not the ones with `!` added.  Like this:

```
pick = <K extends keyof T>(
  ...fields: Array<K | `${Extract<K, string>}!`>
) => {
```

So now `fields` can have exclamations added, but not `K`.  That gives us this behavior:

```
const SubPerson = Person.pick('firstName', 'lastName!');
// const SubPerson: Schema<Record<"firstName" | "lastName", unknown>>

SubPerson.pick(
  'firstName',
  'lastName!',
  'lastName!!' // error
);
```

Where `lastName!!` is rejected, not because the underlying key already ended in an exclamation point, but because the underlying key is just `"lastName"`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAogdgEwM4HUCWwAWMAeBjAGwEMBbI4NAezigF4oADAEgG8lgAnNOAcwF8AhAwBQBCMCgA3AFyxEqDNnzEyFagG5hkulABElANZEQA3VAD05qIeNadusB0oAjMSQD8Zy1AgcnHYWFQSCgARQBXNHEAaQgQJAAeABUfHGAIeWtnACsIPGAAPh1cQnCECASDOMoAMygkgBpGVnYuXkEGAs1g6AANHQio4Fj4hJYoGrQOdgA5UghZcLgDOEoAdzgm4ln5xeXVjabdbeA5kghTPZX1mj4u4W8eqH76XUnp0-mzAB89E7OILpAuYAFRQPCUcIEBBQBCUKBYNBIQJQVFQMBoPAGHQJaKpdKZKogWr1KC-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-RtgvjW1sh09CHlfTzpM7i+NIQEKuimEcuiahaUCM4040Y3lkufVrvo8KTVGvsAKsa+KO6SKOyvqs1AAMnW0G7ehqwtNXzQRwi2RIMajtQOhbTt9pkEK4zvDs5yyAA5AAYsScIcHHTQkGgCAIGIALxwAsmgBiYEQaAEJQkiYpgadQP8uxQHHAAiHHAJQECSEgBggHHc1LX7KUSNa4TOIH0zB-QI9jnAGGSUKcfR585zV3HtfnAIcdLd4-s2kPE-ULItrh3tB0+QkbxTDHgJkn8FoL4Cx1BXAwaBIPw9B1PGJYud9fzwCadqsvN8ARrxmvXFeFw14WCsL4fwwhqpAA)